# Can't save properly a CLOB in hsql with JPA

Tags: jpa, hsqldb, clob

I need to save some long text in an entity using HSQL but it doesn't work.

Here's My JPA annotation

```
@Entity
public class DocPart extends AbstractEntity{
....    
    /**
     * the text of this docPart, exctract from the comment in the odt.
     */
    @Column(columnDefinition = "clob")
    @Lob
    private String text;
....
}
```

When I save this object

```
docPart.setId(1); 
docPart.setText("A text that could be large");
entityManager.persist(docPart);
```

and check in the database instead of the text I get this

```
SELECT text FROM "PUBLIC"."DOCPART"
text
=======================================
org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCClobClient@37c0372c
```

I get this JDBCClobClient@37c0372c thing instead of the text "A text that could be large"

Any idea ?

Comment: What was the SQL invoked to persist it? What is "entityManager.save(...)" ? What is code to retrieve it? What is JPA provider? ...

Comment: The JPA Provider is hibernate, I made a mistake it's entityManager.persist(). The DDL is created by the definition of the entity. The SQL invoked is insert into DocPart (id, annotationName, author, doc_id, pageEnd, pageStart, text) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: If I use this column definition @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGVARCHAR") the long text is properly inserted in the database but LONGVARCHAR is not portable.

Comment: Yes, but then all RDBMS have different types that they support, and you will never find one type that works on all. That is why I'd always leave schema specific things in _orm.xml_ and have an _orm.xml_ for each datastore.

Comment: And Orm.xml is more portable ?

Comment: damn site more portable than hardcoding schema specific things in classes that you would then need to change and recompile to redeploy (which seems to be a requirement for you). IMHO of course ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's working fine and the data is properly inserted. The org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCClobClient@37c0372c shows the data is saved in a CLOB. To retrieve the text, you call the getXXX() methods of the object. The CLOB size could be a gibabyte or more so the normal practice is to retrieve the contents with a Reader object from the clob.

Comment: Ah ok ! I was only using the GUI to check the content of the column. I did not try the getXXX thing. I Guess that if I retreive it through JPA it will work. I'm gonna try and let you know. Thanks.